# Confusion with Snap for polygons (pentagons, hexagons, etc.)

Tags: snapping

Hello everyone The problem with Snap. Guys, explain what this means, why do squares stick normally (cubes too), but pentagons and hexagons don't? I tried both N-gon and triangles and without filling.
[image]

P.S.: Robin Betts, thank you for your help. This is really what we need. But it seems to me that the developers could somehow simplify this, because it is not such a rare function.
In addition to moving, it was also necessary to deal with rotation. Thanks to your hint, I figured out how to do it, thank you.
[image]

Comment: It seems that in object mode the closest point is measured to the selected objects bounding box, the snapping in edit mode is closer to what you are expecting but of course that would mode the object without its origin. I'm not sure what the best way to achieve that kind of snapping would be without moving the objects origin and switching to snap with active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Stoat Paws is right. In Object Mode, 'Closest' uses the bounding box.

In Blender's snapping system, 'Center' means 'Current Transform Center'

So, if, for example, you're working in Object Mode, and set your Snap as follows:

[image]

.. that is to say, snap either to a target 'Vertex' or 'Edge Center' with source: 'Center'..

..and also set your pivot point to '3D Cursor':

[image]

.. then, wherever the 3D Cursor was at the beginning of the move will be snapped to vertices or edge-centers.

The snap also works on the 3D cursor itself. Let's assume the snap magnet is switched off. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> - drag to initiate a movement of the 3D cursor. You can release <kbd>Shift</kbd> once the move is underway. Then holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> enables snap during movement, so you can quickly choose the source-point of your geometry-snap:

[image]